# How can I set a formula with two conditions in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

How can I set a formula with two conditions in Google Spreadsheet?([Sample table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JndyDw5YAKbs2gYSNktb7PREnZ0lpWvFjhk6OX-AVno/edit?usp=sharing))

I want to add more and more names and I need the table be automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this formula works as you want in cell G4:

`=QUERY(A4:C,"select C,sum(B),count(B),avg(A),sum(A),count(A),avg(B) where C<>'' group by C")`

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris! It works! :) Can you please assist me with the second issue in the doc?

Comment: Thank yoy Chris! You are awsm!!

Comment: great, I'm glad that worked. I've thought of a single formula solution which is in cell M25 of your sample sheet, but I think the 2-step approach is simpler.